# Android Studio: when App is rerun settings do not default

Tags: android, android-studio

I clicked on "Run 'app'" in Android Studio and proceeded to run it on the emulator. Then I changed the setting of the app.

After a code change I again clicked on "Run 'app'" but the old settings were picked up. This was even the case with debug.

The only way to get settings to default again was to uninstall from the emulator and then "run 'app'".

Isn't Run App supposed to reinstall the 'app' every time I run? What do I need to get a fresh clean install so that all settings are set to their defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does an upgrade install, and an upgrade install will leave settings intact.

I would say just use command line: `adb uninstall com.example.YourApp`

That is the fastest way to uninstall, which will remove the modified settings.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to uninstalling the app, you can also find your app in the device's settings and use the "Clear data" functionality.